# Adding a Button in Tree View Odoo 8

Tags: odoo-8, odoo

I've Created a Wizard in Tree View Mode and Just Want to add some button with it, is there a way to this in odoo 8?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more details or share a picture?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can add button in the tree view like you are adding in the form view.

```
<tree string="My Tree">
   <button name="%{action_wiz_open}d" string="Scrap Products" type="action" icon="terp-gtk-jump-to-ltr" help="calls window action" />
   <button name="call_function" string="Process" type="object" help="calls python function" />
</tree>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This creates button in each row. How could create button at header or footer of the list view?

Answer (score 1):

To add a button in tree view try below code:

```
 <tree>
    <button name="your_action" icon="rupee-symbol"
                    String="Payment" type="action"
                    attrs="{'invisible':[('status','!=','Confirmed')]}" />
</tree>
```

Hope it will help you..

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder wizard

which will have

```
__init__.py
file_name.py
file_name_view.xml


In Python file_name.py

def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form',
                        context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
        if context is None:
            context={}
        res = super(class_name_wizard, self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, context=context, toolbar=toolbar,submenu=False)
        return res
```

Add your function next to it

In file_name_view.xml

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="new_id">
            <field name="name">New Wizard</field>
            <field name="model">my.wizard</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="New Form"> 
                     <header>
                        <button name="do_generate" string="My Function" type="object"/>
                        or 
                        <button string="Cancel" class ="oe_link" special="cancel"/>
                    </header>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="action_my_function_wizard" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">My Function</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">my.wizard</field>

            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="target">new</field>

        </record>
        <act_window name="My Function"
            res_model="my.wizard"
            src_model="product.master"
            view_mode="form"
            target="new"
            multi="True"
            key2="client_action_multi"
            id="action_view_my_new_id"/>
```

Note:In **src_model** write the table name of the tree view

Hope this will help you